# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating '_this.state.getLeadData[index].menu = _ref2'

Tags: javascript, react-native, ref

Please help. I am not getting meaning of this error and this below code

```
 ref={(ref) => {
                this.state.getLeadData[index].menu = ref;
              }}
```

Comment: Since this is an arrow function `this` is undefined

Comment: so to write this in class component